# jquery events receive and stop not working on droppable lists

Tags: jquery

The HTML is well formed and working correctly, but neither the alerts or the functions are firing; it seems like these just aren't working.  I'm stumped, because it seems strange it would work for the stop:, but nothing else.

I'm persisting the order within tabs successfully, but without these events firing, I'm not sure how to persist moves across tabs without hacking.

```
$( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    stop: function( event, ui ) {

        $('.connectedSortable').each(function() {
            if($("#"+this.id).length > 0){
                var margin_id = $(this).attr('margin_id');
                var group_id = $(this).attr('group_id');
                var sortedIDs = $( "#"+this.id ).sortable( "toArray" );
                console.log(sortedIDs);
                update_widget_order(sortedIDs,__user_id,__page_id,margin_id,group_id);

            }
        });

        // Update widget order

    },
    receive: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('test');
        $('.connectedSortable').each(function() {
            if($("#"+this.id).length > 0){
                var margin_id = $(this).attr('margin_id');
                var group_id = $(this).attr('group_id');
                var sortedIDs = $( "#"+this.id ).sortable( "toArray" );
                console.log(sortedIDs);
                update_widget_order(sortedIDs,__user_id,__page_id,margin_id,group_id);
            }
        });
    }
    ,
    remove: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('remove');
        /*$('.connectedSortable').each(function() {
            if($("#"+this.id).length > 0){
                var margin_id = $(this).attr('margin_id');
                var group_id = $(this).attr('group_id');
                var sortedIDs = $( "#"+this.id ).sortable( "toArray" );
                console.log(sortedIDs);
                update_widget_order(sortedIDs,__user_id,__page_id,margin_id,group_id);
            }
        });*/
    }

}).disableSelection();
```